# Wagtail Migration error when removing Streamfield block

Tags: django, wagtail

I had a Streamfield block based on SnippetChooserBlock which I removed, which was fine, migrations were fine.

```
('call_to_action_snippet', SnippetChooserBlock(CallToActionSnippet,icon="success",template='myapp/blocks/cta_snippet.html')),
```

When I then tried to then also remove the CallToActionSnippet from my models, I get an error when running makemigrations from an older migration file:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CallToActionSnippet'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I know SF custom blocks can't be removed if they're based on certain block types but I thought a SnippetChooserBlock would be ok.

thanks

Joss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't with the `SnippetChooserBlock` directly but with your snippet `CallToActionSnippet` which I imagine you removed?

If you have a look at the migration where this Streamfield was initially created, you should see something like `wagtail.wagtailsnippets.blocks.SnippetChooserBlock(yourapp.snippets.CallToActionSnippet)`. However, because you removed the snippet, when the migration tries to load, it fails.

The target model of a `SnippetChooserBlock` can be passed as a `appname.modelname` type string (which is later [lazily loaded](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/026346b977ab80649dcffcb4f5a6e2d4f9034125/wagtail/wagtailsnippets/blocks.py#L16)). So instead of passing an instance of the model to `wagtail.wagtailsnippets.blocks.SnippetChooserBlock` in the migration, edit it to pass a string `'yourapp.CallToActionSnippet'`.

Comment: Thanks for that, i see what you mean. I'm probably going to remove all the migrations and start from scratch with my models, as there's no data really at this point. Is there someway I could have avoided this though from that start, so going forward I don't make this mistake again. When I referenced the snippet in my model should I have used an appname.modelname string at that point?

Comment: Indeed. Using `SnippetChooserBlock(CallToActionSnippet)` in the StreamField definition will generate `wagtail.wagtailsnippets.blocks.SnippetChooserBlock(yourapp.snippets.CallToActionSnippet)` while using `SnippetChooserBlock('core.CallToActionSnippet')` will generate `wagtail.wagtailsnippets.blocks.SnippetChooserBlock('core.CallToActionSnippet')` which wouldn't cause the import error.